# Ubuntu Server replace Windows 7 as my home server?

Tags: server, minecraft, teamspeak

I currently have a home server running Windows 7 pro just so I can run my kids Minecraft server and also a Teamspeak server for online gaming.

I would love to know if i can replace Win7 with Ubuntu or Debian and still have the same result?

Im not new to Linux but have never run a Linux Server before so im no whizz on the cmd line

any tips or ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, install ssh and sshfs on the server, so you can access it remotely and copy files on it via internet.
Then, install samba filesharing, so you can access network shares from your windows machine.
If you want to be able to access your windows files from the internet, you need to install a webserver that supports webdav + webdav itselfs.

You can generate a ssh-key so you don't need to enter the password.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

echo /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

login to your server via ssh.

```
cd /home/username/.ssh/
cat "OUTPUT FROM echo id_rsa.pub" >> authorized_keys
```

you can mount a sshfs file system like this:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/sshfs
sshfs 192.168.1.x:/ /mnt/sshfs
```

then you can access the server file system via /mnt/sshfs

You can also use x-forwarding:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.2 -X
```

Then you can start whatever graphical application on your console-only server.

Here are two minecraft server tutorials

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-a-minecraft-server-on-linux

http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Linux_instructions

And this is how to setup teamspeak

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-a-teamspeak-server-on-ubuntu

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=236834

Comment: so right now i use another windows machine to access the server via teamviewer as the server has no screen, how would i do that?

Comment: @Zabadda: Install virtualbox on your windows machine, install a ubuntu desktop virtual machine, and set networking to "bridge mode". Then you can access your linux server from your linux vm, and let virtualbox + guest additions handle the data-exchange with windows. This is the easiest way. Otherwise, it's rather nasty. You could try putty or google git shell, which supports ssh. But any ssh client would do. There also exists a port of sshfs for windows, it's called dokan sshfs.

Comment: blimey loads there thanks :) i think ill need a step by step guide to work all that out lol ill have a search though now I know its possible